# The content div shadow is not displaying

Tags: html, css

This is a code from my recent project, as I am a newbie this code may lack some standards.

html example page without featured slider

the class I have defined for shadow is named as 'sawli'

### code HTML

```
<div id="container-o">
<!-- Start of Main -->
<div id="main" class="sawli">
<div id="content">
<h1>Welcome to SEOCrust</h1><hr />
<p>This is a Parragraph Text</p>
</div>
</div><!-- End of Main -->
```

---

### Css for that

```
#container-o{ /*Main container*/
    width:70%;
    display:block;
    padding:0;
    margin-top:-280px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:relative;
}
#container-o p{
    font-size:18px;
}

#main{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:20px auto;
    border:0px;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
.sawli {
    box-shadow:6px 0 4px  -4px #222 , -6px 0 4px  -4px #222;
    -moz-box-shadow:6px 0 4px  -4px #222 , -6px 0 4px  -4px #222;
    -webkit-box-shadow:6px 0 4px  -4px #222 , -6px 0 4px  -4px #222;    
}
#main #content{
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
}
```

this is a snippet of my code.

please help me!

Comment: *Unable to access the links as I am behind corporate firewall.*

Comment: @PraveenKumar You shouldn't be accessing StackOverflow too..Back to work..lol

Comment: @Mr.Alien Only knowledge stuff is this... :P Yeah, my people are restricting me to StackOverflow. Lets deal with it! :P

Comment: @PraveenKumar same here :p

Comment: Please do **not** use a file sharer to show us code. Paste the relevant code here itself, preferably width a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: As you can see, guys, this poor guy is newbie. And you decided to close his post. I really don't think this is a polite solution for StackOverflow... I think the solution is to help and explain him how to use it for future questions, even if StackOverflow has it's own section for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two id's for the same div. Try to change id="sawli" to class="sawli", and then change on your CSS:

```
#sawli { ... }
```

to

```
.sawli { ... }
```

You're not allowed to use two identifiers on the same object. But you can combine an identifier and a class.

Could you please copy your code here so we can have a look better than downloading your code?

See this:

http://jsfiddle.net/CDe3E/

Actually you can remove some staff:

http://jsfiddle.net/CDe3E/1/

See if that's what you want.

Comment: I used the both id and class but nothing happened.

Comment: i have edited my post please take a look.

Comment: Take a look to this jFiddle I did for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/CDe3E/

Comment: Thanks Sonhja. I just removed unnecessary container div and applied only important property to such divs. Thanks once again!!